# Find and replace in a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, bookmarklet

What I want to do is replace all instances of 'foo' in a webpage with 'bar' in a JS bookmarklet/greasemonkey script.  How can I do this?  I suppose jQuery works, as there're hacks to include those in both bookmarklets and greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: "Not trying to be lazy" - guess it comes to you without effort! <evil grin>

Make your title a short summary with enough information to help people would be interested find your question; provide the details in the body.

Comment: Could you please give an example of what a good way to split it up might be?  Sorry, new to this!

Answer (score 13):

This script iterates through each element in the document and replaces every instance of `foo` with `bar`.

The `gi` modifiers on the regex make it do a [global](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp), [case-insensitive](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) search.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/foo/gi, 'bar');
}
```

You can target specific tag names by changing the `"*"` to the tag name of your choice (e.g. `"p"`, `"td"`).

Comment: Why not just `document.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/gi, 'bar');`? Grabbing all of the elements as you suggest can cause recursive replacement when elements are nested.

Comment: @ændrük should be ``document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/gi, 'bar')``. See [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29316601/1933185).

Comment: Modifying innerHTML, which inculdes each element's children, is a very bad advice because it'll break lots/most of pages that use addEventListener and element references. Use TreeWalker API: [Replace many text terms, using Tampermonkey, without affecting URLs and not looking for classes or ids](//stackoverflow.com/a/24419809)

Comment: I wonder what compels people to take the time comment on (and try to "correct") accepted answers from over eight years ago.  Truly bizarre.

Comment: Probably because it's a valid criticism, and this is the first result in Google for certain terms, making it rather important.

Comment: That's why I'm here! This is exactly what I was looking for and it was the first Bing result.