# I want to create a bookmarklet that will search for a text and replace with a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So, I want to search for a text (say "wikipedia") and have all the "wikipedia" in the page turn into a link that redirects to wikipedia.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find and replace in a webpage using javascript.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155353/find-and-replace-in-a-webpage-using-javascript)

Comment: well good luck with that, let us know if you get stuck on anything.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt do this by using the solution linked by VoteyDisciple, walking all elements could take a long time, and replacing innerHTML could lead you to unwanted results, while this will not only access TextNodes.

I would prefer textRanges to do this.

in MSIE:
find the string with [findText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and replace it using [pasteHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536656%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

in others(except opera):
find the string with [window.find()](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php) and surround it using [surroundContents()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Surrounding)

For opera I actually dont know a method how to find text, maybe there is an opera-specific method available.