# Browsing back doesn't work the same with greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916340/using-only-cr-as-linebreak-inside-pre-tag-doesnt-work) where I found a strange workaround for a problem using this greasemonkey script:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
}
```

One of my coworkers now showed me the following: When you do a bugzilla database query, you fill some textfields, select some dropdown items etc. Usually, those are remembered when you use the browser's back button to get back to the query page, but when this script is active, they aren't.

Is this a general problem with using greasemonkey scripts and is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself. Apparently the query page itself was modified by the script right after navigating back to it and lost all saved form data in this process. Adding the query page URL to the list of excluded URLs solved the problem.