# Linebreaks missing from json in AngularJS ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs

I'm posting a form to an ASP.Net MVC action that returns a JSON object. This object is received, parsed and bound correctly. So I know the service is working correctly and the data is understandable.

The issue is that I have a string that may contain line breaks `/r` that are getting removed at some point.

This is the JSON coming into the browser captured in Chrome's network->response tab.

```
   "PropertyModel":{"Id":6131,"Ref":"61267","Address":"16\rSpringfield Green\rHunslet","PostCode":"LS10 2EJ  "}
```

However in my view these aren't rendered. Regardless of whether I wrap it in a `<pre>` or use `white-space:pre;`

How do i go about getting my `/n` back!?

Comment: I think you need to escape the codes in the JSON: `\\r`.

Comment: Have you got any code that you can show us, so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm not doing any processing of the returned data. Just assigning it to a scope var then binding to it using curly braces in the view. It's not going through any filters or anything.

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916340/using-only-cr-as-linebreak-inside-pre-tag-doesnt-work Use \n or \r\n rather than just \r.